# In an Android Gallery, how do you listen to a locked in image?

Tags: android, android-gallery

When I flip through an Android Gallery, it moves to an image and the focus locks in on it.  Which event should I listen to for the image lock in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
mCoverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
    {
        // position will give you the locked item
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {
    }
});
```